# Joining a table into itself with results to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to grab some information out of a manufacturing system which tracks what parts are used when assembling a device. All the data is in the same table, devices, modules and components. A device is is made out of modules and components, and both are registered as assemblies (ASSY) with a serial no. The COMP column is used to register which components go into a module, as well as which components and modules go into a device. The INVENTORY_ID column tracks which module goes into what device.

The basic table structure is like this:

```
SERIALNO ASSY ASSYREV COMP  COMPREV ORDERNO  ASSEMBLED_DATE_TIME     INVENTORY_ID  COMP_SERIALNUMBER
======== ==== ======= ====  ======= =======  ======================= ============= ==================
499222   M1   V005    C1    F       NULL     2013-11-14 04:08:46.000 NULL          50879
499223   M1   V005    C1    F       NULL     2013-11-14 04:11:30.000 NULL          50947
499224   M1   V002    C1    B       NULL     2013-11-14 04:13:58.000 NULL          50939
502270   D1   A       M1    V005    20532642 2013-11-15 09:10:47.000 499222        NULL
502277   D2   A       M1    V002    20532641 2013-11-15 08:59:49.000 499224        NULL
502479   D3   A       M1    V005    20532647 2013-11-15 09:32:15.000 499223        NULL
502270   D1   A       C2    F       20532642 2013-11-15 09:10:47.000 NULL          43542
502270   D1   A       M2    V011    20532642 2013-11-15 09:10:00.000 498644        NULL
```

So, my question is, I need to get information about what devices the component C1 with COMPREV F has been assembled into (via a module). The result should look something like below. Can this be accomplished with a single query?

```
SERIALNO ASSY COMP COMPREV ORDERNO  ASSEMBLED_DATE_TIME      COMP_SERIALNO
======== ==== ==== ======= ======== ======================== =============
502270   D1   C1   F       20532642 2013-11-15 09:10:47.000  50879   
502479   D3   C1   F       20532647 2013-11-15 09:32:15.000  50947
```

Comment: did n't you forget to describe `COMP_SERIALNO` in your result?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, I believe this is what you want:

```
select  t2.SERIALNO, t2.ASSY, t1.COMP, t1.COMPREV, t2.ORDERNO, t2.ASSEMBLED_DATE_TIME, COMP_SERIALNO = t1.SERIALNO
from    bigtable t1
join    bigtable t2 on t1.ASSY = t2.COMP and t1.SERIAL_NO = INVENTORY_ID
where   t1.COMP = 'C1'
and     t1.COMPREV = 'F'
```

I wasn't sure about the COMP_SERIALNO column because the values you listed don't correspond to anything in the main table.